# using jQuery animate a div from top to bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using this code and it's working correct moving from top to bottom but i want to move continuously not single time. Thanks!!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
     var footerOffsetTop = $('#moving').offset().top;
     var topToBottom = bodyHeight -footerOffsetTop;
     $('#moving').css({top:'auto',bottom:topToBottom});
     $("#moving").delay(100).animate({
     top: '100px',
     }, 3000);  
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
        var footerOffsetTop = $('#moving').offset().top;
        var topToBottom = bodyHeight - footerOffsetTop;
        $('#moving').css({
            top : 'auto',
            bottom : topToBottom
        });
        $("#moving").delay(100).animate({
            top : '100px',
        }, 3000);       
    }, 3200);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't want fade in fade out. After coming from top its start fade in. It should move continuously

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
    var footerOffsetTop = $('#moving').offset().top;
    var topToBottom = bodyHeight - footerOffsetTop - $('#moving').outerHeight();

    $("#moving").animate({
        top : topToBottom,
    }, 3000);
});
```

**Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/c9db5/**

You don't need `setInterval` here at all. You just need to work out the height of your screen minus the height of the `#moving` div and then you can get it to animate in one go.